# Contar e remover dados duplicados em array de objetos Angular

Tags: html, array, angular, typescript, front-end

Estou recebendo um array de objetos onde cada objeto contém vários dados e preciso mostrar o dado `name` em tela, de forma que mostre o `name` apenas uma vez e do lado a quantidade de vezes em que ele apareceu. Caso não seja repetido aparecerá apenas uma vez com um `x1` ao lado.
Tentei utilizar o `filter`, mas não consegui, apenas utilizando o `ngFor` para acessar o `name` no HTML e mesmo assim só aparece a lista com todos os `name` dos objetos, repetidos ou não.

`[{...}, {...}, {...},{...}]`

Edit: a quantidade de vezes em que aparece o dado consigo resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar o [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const x = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'},{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]

const result = x.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(acc.find(item => item.name === curr.name)) return acc;
    return [...acc, curr]
}, []);
```